# Merge Data from Multiple List<SObject> for use in Update/Insert

Tags: apex, soql, list

I'm attempting to rollup some Activity data to Campaign Members from a Trigger event. I've already worked through my trigger/filtering logic and now I have a list of affected campaign members:

```
List<CampaignMember> campaign_members = CampaignUtils.listCampaignMembersByWhoId(whoId_list); /* 1 SOQL */
```

As well as a list of Recent Activities per Lead/Contact (which is the `WhoId`):

```
List<ActivityHistory> recent_activities = CampaignUtils.fetchRecentActivityForCampaginMembers(campaign_members,true);
```

> ***Example Instance:** 20+ activities are updated, between 3 Leads/Contacts, producing 6 Campaign Members affected =`List<CampaignMember> campaign_members`, as well as 3 recent activities, (1 per Who [ContactId/LeadId]) =`List<ActivityHistory> recent_activities`

So with these 2 list I need to merge or update the `campaign_members` fields with data in the `recent_activities`. For example:

```
campaign_members.F2F_Activity_Date__c = recent_activities.ActivityDate
```

BUT, this is based on matching `WhoId`(s). I'm thinking I need a loop of some sort but not sure how to say, for each `campaign_members` find the matching `recent_activity`, and then add that activity data to this member.

Thanks in advance for any help!

> **EDIT:** My current attempt looks something like this

```
for (CampaignMember member : campaign_members) {
    for(ActivityHistory act : recent_activities){
        if (act.WhoId == member.LeadId || act.WhoId == member.ContactId) {
            campaign_members.get(**THIS MEMBER**).F2F_Activity_ID__c = act.Id;
            campaign_members.get(member).custom_field__c = act.value;
        }
    }
}
update campaign_members;
```

Comment: What object is the trigger on?

Comment: One on Task and Event because those make up Activities in SF. Does that matter for this though?

Comment: It matters, I'm just still trying to wrap my head around what you are trying to do so I can answer the question.  Sorry!

Comment: No worries just making sure. The goal is when an activity is inserted or updated to rollup details _(recent activity details, number of activities, etc.)_ to the campaign member objects for any Lead/Contact that is part of an active campaign during that activity

Comment: I guess I still don't 100% get it, but I can try.  Are you having trouble finding the Activity that matches with the CampaignMember?  I bet it's because there could potentially be more than 1 activity per CampaignMember

Comment: In my example above lets pretend LEAD Luke is part of 2 Campaigns, that means there are 2 CampaignMembers in the `campaign_members` LIST with his LeadId in it, BUT only 1 most recent activity in the `recent_activities` LIST. So as I iterate through all `campaign_members` as I have in my edited section, I just need to add the activity data to the specific iteration of that member and I don't know to get that, trying .get() now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20311/discussion-between-xtremefaith-and-bradley-delaune).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you provided, you are very close.  The only thing you need to understand is that in the Java world (and therefore the Apex world), any non-primitive data types are pass-by-reference.  Your example will look something like this to work:

```
Map activityMap = new Map();
for (ActivityHistory act: recent_Activities) {
  activityMap.put(act.WhoId,act);
}

for (CampaignMember member : campaign_members) {
    if(activityMap.containsKey(member.ContactId)){
        member.F2F_Activity_ID__c = activityMap.get(member.ContactId).Id;
        member.custom_field__c = activityMap.get(member.ContactId).value;
    }
}
update campaign_members;
```

In addition to fix the issue you will also want to prevent the nested for loops. You'll see how I used a Map to prevent that.

Comment: -1 While you technically answered the question, you avoided the real problem, which is the performance bottleneck that will occur from using a nested loop like this.

Comment: @sfdcfox I agree. I helped him on chat with that as well. I suppose I should update my answer with the performance enhancements as well?

Comment: Your answer looks much better now!

Comment: Thanks! Still relatively new to stack exchange and tend to forget where to put information.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid nested loops and use a `Map` instead. Since WhoId is not unique among your `ActivityHistory` records, you should ideally use `Map<Id, List<ActivityHistory>>`, but in this case it looks like you will arbitrarily pick which `ActivityHistory` to use, so `Map<Id, ActivityHistory` will probably suffice.

```
static void updateCampaignMembers(List<CampaignMember> campaign_members, List<ActivityHistory> recent_activities)
{
    Map<Id, ActivityHistory> whoIdToHistory = new Map<Id, ActivityHistory>();
    for (ActivityHistory history : recent_activities)
    {
        whoIdToHistory.put(history.WhoId, history);
    }

    for (CampaignMember member : campaign_members)
    {
        ActivityHistory leadMatch = whoIdToHistory.get(member.LeadId);
        ActivityHistory contactMatch = whoIdToHistory.get(member.ContactId);
        if (leadMatch != null) mergeValues(member, leadMatch);
        if (contactMatch != null) mergeValues(member, contactMatch);
    }
    update campaign_members;
}

static void mergeValues(CampaignMember member, ActivityHistory history)
{
    if (history == null) return;
    member.F2F_Activity_ID__c = history.Id;
    member.custom_field__c = history.value;
}
```